# Drawing drawable in canvas doesn't work

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to draw a drawable on canvas with this code but it doesn't work and i don't know why

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.allergist).draw(canvas);
```

I set my custom views heigh and width to match parent but whole screen is white and there is no drawable on screen

Comment: you didnt set `Drawable`'s bounds

Comment: thanks that solved @pskink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You need to load your `image` as `bitmap`:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.allergist);
```

> Then make the `bitmap mutable` and create a canvas over it:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
```

> After that you can draw it on canvas.

**EDIT 1**

> Set bounds To `Drawable`.

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.allergist);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: but i have a sample project that uses drawable.draw(); and its working

Comment: Then may be the problem with your `Drawable image` which you are using. check with that.

Comment: @jaydroider who said `R.drawable.allergist` points to a png / jpg image?

Comment: @Amir_P You can check i have edited answer for same to set bounds.

Comment: Yes @pskink Sir may be it could be anything `png / jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and we solved it by calling drawable.invalidateSelf(). After that, it rendered successfully onto our Canvas.